# Duda rollback innecesario en PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, transacciones

Estoy comenzando a usar **TRANSACCIONES** en **PHP/MySQL** pero estoy observando la siguiente situación:

En mis pruebas he notado que **rollback** no es necesario aunque he leído que siempre se ponen para regresar los datos a su estado original si se produce un error, pero mi duda surge por el siguiente ejemplo:

```
1.- deshabilito autocommit.
2.- realizo las querys necesarias.
3.- valido si se realizaron todas la querys.
4.- SI SE realizaron todas lanzar commit (guardar los datos de forma permanente).
5.- SI NO se realizaron todas lanzar rollback (retroceso de datos).
```

**En esta situación mi duda es la siguiente:**

Entiendo que al deshabilitar **autocommit**, no se va a registrar nada en la base de datos, hasta ejecutar un **commit**. Dicho esto no veo necesario un **rollback**, ya que nunca se registraron en la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Te has acordado de lanzar un [`BEGIN` o `START TRANSACTION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html)? ¿Usas mysqli o PDO/mysql? Deberías usar el soporte para transacciones que implementan en vez de lanzar las consultas tú mismo. Se encargan de gestionar automáticamente el autocommit, etc.

Comment: Utilizo mysqli, y el código que intenté utilizar es `mysqli_begin_transaction($link,MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY);` pero me guardaba en la base de datos los query ejecutados antes del query con error y no pude hacer que funcionara correctamente, hasta que intenté deshabilitando **autocommit** y me funcionó bien por eso ya no intenté usarlo.

Comment: Sí, autocommit debe desactivarse de manera explícita. Recuerda comenzar explícitamente una transacción. `MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY` no permite modificaciones (*The `READ ONLY` restriction prevents the transaction from modifying or locking both transactional and nontransactional tables that are visible to other transactions; the transaction can still modify or lock temporary tables.*). ¿Podrías especificar tu duda en la pregunta? No tengo muy claro qué quieres preguntar, qué error estás obteniendo o qué te ocurre. Sí, MySQL hace rollback de las transacciones en caso de desconexión prematura.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya pude hacer que funcionara utilizando `MYSQLI_TRANS_START_WITH_CONSISTENT_SNAPSHOT` pero sigo teniendo la misma duda con respecto a **rollback**  ya que si no lo pongo tiene el mismo efecto que si lo pusiera. ¿Es necesario ponerlo?.

Comment: Es necesario ponerlo si vas a seguir trabajando con la misma conexión para hacer otras tareas. Siempre es preferible hacer las cosas de manera explícita que dejar que de manera implícita se hagan.

Comment: El problema es que en tu punto 3, intentas sustituir a las transacciones: `3.- valido si se realizaron todas la querys.` ... si usas transacciones eso no debe ser tarea tuya, para eso existen las transacciones precisamente. Si haces las cosas correctamente, como ha dicho @OscarGarcia, no tienes por qué validar nada por tu cuenta. Además, ¿qué forma tienes tú de validar que una consulta o grupo de consultas de tipo `INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE` se ejecutaron con éxito y al mismo tiempo revertirlas? Eso sólo puede hacerlo las transacciones, de hecho, para eso existen.

Comment: @A.Cedano quiere decirte, entre otras cosas, que la validez debe comprobarse de manera implícita. Por ejemplo, saber si existe previamente o no un registro no debe hacerse haciendo un `SELECT` previo, si no teniendo correctamente configurada una clave única y que al hacer el `INSERT` te falle por clave duplicada (por ponerte un ejemplo), comprobaciones de rangos o validez de datos deben realizarse previamente. De las pocas comprobaciones que deben validarse dentro de una transacción es, por poner otro ejemplo, la disponibilidad de stock o fondos.

Comment: ¿Alguna duda más con esta pregunta? ¿La respuesta aclara o responde a tu pregunta?

Comment: Acabo de ver las respuestas, el efecto estaba haciendo mal las cosas, al menos las validaciones que hice y que ya van implícitas. Voy a corregir mis códigos, muchas gracias gracias!.

Comment: Si mi respuesta respondió tu duda agradecería que la marcaras como correcta para dar por cerrada esta pregunta. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

**Entiendo que al deshabilitar autocommit, no se va a registrar nada en la base de datos, hasta ejecutar un commit, dicho esto no veo necesario un rollback, ya que nunca se registraron en la base de datos.**

Es **necesario** hacer un `ROLLBACK` siempre que vayas a seguir haciendo consultas ya que [una nueva transacción hará `COMMIT` de la anterior](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html):

> *Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit:*
>
> - [...]
> - Transaction-control and locking statements. `BEGIN`, `LOCK TABLES`,
>     `SET autocommit = 1` (if the value is not already 1), `START TRANSACTION`, `UNLOCK TABLES`.
> - [...]

En castellano:

> *Consultas que causan un COMMIT implícito:*
>
> - [...]
> - Consultas de control de transacciones y bloqueo. `BEGIN`, `LOCK TABLES`, `SET autocommit = 1` (si el valor no era ya 1), `START TRANSACTION`, `UNLOCK TABLES`.
> - [...]

Si estás completamente seguro que no harás ninguna consulta más podrías no hacer el `ROLLBACK`para que MySQL haga uno implícito al finalizar la conexión, pero yo prefiero (y te recomiendo) hacerlo de manera explícita.